# How to convert this JS to jQuery? Need to add fade effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple JavaScript to make a hidden `div` appear on `img` hover:

```
document.onmouseover = quickView;

function quickView(e) {
    (!e) var e = window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var bWide = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;

    if(target.className == 'p-image') {
        var dTarg = target.parentNode.lastChild;
        dTarg.style.visibility = 'visible';
        dTarg.style.top = (target.parentNode.offsetTop - 110) + 'px';
        if (target.parentNode.offsetLeft < (bWide * .5)) {
            dTarg.style.left = (target.parentNode.offsetLeft + 185) + 'px';     
        }

        if (target.parentNode.offsetLeft >= (bWide * .1801)) {
            dTarg.style.left = (target.parentNode.offsetLeft - 497) + 'px'; 
        }

        target.onmouseout = hideQuickView;
    }
}

function hideQuickView(e) {
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    target.parentNode.lastChild.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

What I need is to add a `fadein` and `fadeout` effect instead of just visible / hidden.
Also a delay in `fadein` would be great. I know some jQuery but this is old JS, how can I add the fade effects?

Thank you very much

EDIT: 
i managed to fadein the hiddendiv but it will not allways fadein. If i move the mouse very fast to another hidden div the effect will not work anymore.I need to wait sometime for the fade to work again. I mean the code is not an accurate solution.
As i said the hover class is called p-image and the hidden class is called quickview.
This is the jQuery, but i would prefere if i can edit the original JavaScript somehow to include the delay fade there.

`$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".p-image").hover(function () {
          jQuery(".quickview").css("opacity", .20);
      jQuery(".quickview").fadeTo(430, 1);
    });
    return true;
  });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use jQuery's `fadeIn` function to fade elements in and `fadeOut` to fade them out. Then use `delay` with `fadeIn` if you want a delay, `$( "selector" ).delay( 500 ).fadeIn()`

```
$( document ).on( "mouseover", function( e ) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var $target = $( e.target || e.srcElement );
    var bWide = $( window ).width();
    if ( $target.hasClass( "p-image" ) )
    {
        var $dTarg = $target.parent().children().last();
        var targOffset = $target.parent().offset();
        $dTarg.fadeIn().css( "top", targOffset.top - 110 + "px" );
        if ( targOffset.left < ( bWide * .5 ) )
        {
            $dTarg.css( "left", $targOffset.left + 185 + 'px' );
        }
        else if ( targOffset.left >=  ( bWide * .1801 ) )
        {
            $dTarg.css( "left", $targOffset.left - 497 + 'px' );
        }
        $target.on( "mouseout", hideQuickView );
    }
});

// You should be able to figure out hideQuickView implementation.
```

Answer (score 2):

add jQuery to your site and use `$(selector).fadeIn();` and `$(selector).fadeOut();` 
selector can be any css selector e.g. `$('#element_id').fadeIn()` 
replace the bit of code where you hide/show the elements with the jquery bits. you can leave the rest in normal js. 
 to change the duration of the fade add an argument to the function e.g. `$(element).fadeIn(400);` will make the fade last 400ms
[more information here](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

Comment: hmm this is what i was thiking in the first place, thank you, let me try how it will work

Answer (score 0):

```
$(dTarg).fadeIn("1000")
```

This fades the stuff in in 1 sec.

You must also change the css for the dTarg item from

```
visibility:hidden
```

to

```
display:none
```

Comment: Hi thanks for all the replys.The name of the hidden div that will hover the big img on hover is not dTarg but it is quickview.strange is that i get "quickview is not defined"